# How to make footer respect absolute positioned contents height?

Tags: css, sass

I have the following page:

- title top left
- image below title with max width
- links below the image on the left side
- page content nicely aligned on the right side of the image
- a footer (the problem)

I'm using absolute positioning to position my content next to the image. Not sure if this is possible with inline-block or floats, which would solve my problem.

My issue now is that the footer overlaps my content because the absolute positioned content loses it's height.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sc3e1t15/

```css
.wrapper { position: relative; }
.title,
.footer  { font-weight: bold; }
.image   { font-style: italic; width: 210px; border: 1px solid red; }
.links   { max-width: 210px; }
.content { position: absolute; top: 18px; left: 220px; border: 1px solid green; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">
    I'm the title.
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    I'm an image.
  </div>
  <div class="links">
    I'm some links.<br>
    I want to be on the left side too!
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    I'm the content.<br>
    I want to be shown neatly next to the image.<br>
    Spread over multiple lines<br>
    Nothing to see here<br>
    Staph reading me!<br>
    Love you brah.
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    I'm a problem ... Because I disrespect the contents height.
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: issue]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this.**wrap content you want in left side and give it display property.**

{display: inline-block;}

**No need of using position here.**

```css
.wrapper { position: relative; }
.title,
.footer  { font-weight: bold; }
.image   { font-style: italic; width: 210px; border: 1px solid red; }
.links   { max-width: 210px; }
.content { display:inline-block; border: 1px solid green; }
.left-contain { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="title">
    I'm the title.
  </div>
 <div class="left-contain">
  <div class="image">
    I'm an image.
  </div>
  <div class="links">
    I'm some links.<br>
    I want to be on the left side too!
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="content">
    I'm the content.<br>
    I want to be shown neatly next to the image.<br>
    Spread over multiple lines<br>
    Nothing to see here<br>
    Staph reading me!<br>
    Love you brah.
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    I'm a problem ... Because I disrespect the contents height.
  </div>
</div>
```